# ValueTuples lose their property names when serialized

Tags: c#, json.net, tuples, valuetuple

While trying to serialize a named value tuple to JSON string, it loses the names assigned to items

```
(string type, string text) myTypes = ("A", "I am an animal");
var cnvValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myTypes);
```

I am expecting the serialized value as

> {"type":"A","text":"I am an animal"}

but the actual results are

> {"Item1":"A","Item2":"I am an animal"}

There are two things that i am interested to know

- Why does it behave like that
- How to get the expected output

Comment: FYI https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1505

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> How to get the expected output

Something like this:

```
var myTypes = new{ type = "A", text = "I am an animal"};
var cnvValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myTypes);
```

should work if you’re looking for a similarly terse approach. Doesn’t use `ValueTuple`s (but anonymous types) under the hood though; this is my interpreting your question as “how can I produce this expected JSON without going to the full extent of declaring a class etc”

Comment: You interpreted it in the correct sense. I used ValueTuples to do exactly that.

Answer (score 20):

The names are a compiler trick. If you look at the definition for [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-3?view=netframework-4.7.2) you'll see that its field names are just `Item1`, `Item2`, etc.

Since `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` was compiled well before you assigned names that you could use during *your* compilation, it cannot recover the names.

Method parameters/return types are decorated with [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.tupleelementnamesattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) that indicate the names to be used when a method's signature includes `ValueTuple`s. This allows code authored later to "see" the names by the compiler playing tricks again, but that's the "wrong way around" to be of much use here.

> How to get the expected output

Introduce an explicit type, if the names of the fields/properties are so important.

Comment: Important to note that the explicit type could be an *anonymous type*.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan *Anonymous type* are not explicit anyway

Comment: I do not want to create an explicit type to use it only once. But still I want the names of items to appear in JSON string.

Comment: If you want the better names, you need to at least use an anonymous type, or a named type. `ValueTuple` will not help you, as you've seen.

Answer (score 3):

> How to get the expected output

Use explicit custom type or anonymous class like in @Caius answer.

Or don't create special type for it at all (for anonymous type compiler generates class behind the scene for you) and use [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm) to dynamically create json:

```
var myTypesJson = new JObject(
    new JProperty("type", "A"), 
    new JProperty("text", "I am an animal")
);
var cnvValue = myTypesJson.ToString();
```

or use indexer and initialization [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#initialize-associative-collections-using-indexers) for it:

```
var createdJson = new JObject()
{
    ["type"] = "A",
    ["text"] = "I am an animal"
};
var cnvValue = createdJson.ToString();
```